# UItabbar item font change when change the frame of tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I am using below code for hiding my tab bar

[self.tabBarController.tabBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -50, 0, 0)];

Now when I come back again on that view and show the tab bar it's font change. for again showing tab bar I am using this code.

```
     [self.tabBarController.tabBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-49, self.view.frame.size.width, 49)];
```

Please have a look on screen shot

[!the red circle font is a bug I am not setting font in my code or in storyboard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRK6o.png) ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRK6o.png)

[image: Please check it]

[image: screen shot of my storyboard]

please suggest me why my tab bar items font change when I resume it's frame to previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bellow code for hiding the Tab bar.

```
-(BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed
 {
  return YES;
 }
```

Then your problem is solve.

Comment: Thanks for answer,  it is not a delegate method so when and where should I call it?

Comment: You have A and B classes, when ever your pushing A to B then this code write in B Class.

Comment: Can you please explain logic behind it.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621863-hidesbottombarwhenpushed?language=objc